# Choosing between chi-squared / logistic regression vs difference of mean tests for studying bankruptices

Tags: logistic, t-test, chi-squared-test, logit, method-comparison

You'd expect more companies to go bankrupt if they have low cash balances.  Of course, bankruptcies can also happen even when you have lot of cash on hand (to terminate labor contracts, etc.).

The distributions are shown below:

[image]

A `chi-squared` test shows an association of bankruptcies with cash-on-hand.  I then check the results using `logistic regression` which actually gives me negative coefficients for low cash balances! (Using LR is fine as I have ~2000 positives for ~150k observations).

I'm thinking about a simple `difference of means test` to show that cash balances for bankruptcies differ than those for healthy companies.  Do you suggest any other statistical test that I can use instead?

Comment: If your aim is actually prediction, hypothesis tests would seem to be the wrong tool altogether. Wouldn't out-of-sample predictive ability be a way to identify a good predictive model, suggesting sample splitting / cross validation and like approaches?

Comment: @Glen_b You are right if I was developing a prediction model.  Right now, I'm just trying to focus on proving that relationship exists.  Do I still need to split the data into 3 samples?  Also, since this is a rare event LR, any sample splitting can hurt MLE calculations.  Is it completely wrong to use the entire sample for LR?  If I was choosing between prediction models, I might have tested with different threshold levels, plotted ROCs etc.  But right now, my focus is just to prove that coefficients are in line with my theory. Please comment.

Comment: The word 'predicting' is right in your title. If that's *not* what you're doing, why use the word?

Comment: @Glen_b I have changed it to studying/understanding!  Does my comment about not using sample splitting hold correct now?

Comment: My comment about prediction is no longer relevant; if the theory came before you saw the data there'd be no need to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think logistic regression is probably the right tool for you to use.  However, if you only want to establish that the relationship exists, and you ran a chi-squared test first, which was significant, it isn't clear that you need to keep trying additional analyses.

It is hard to tell from your plots, but the raw numbers of bankruptcies seems to follow the patter of the raw numbers of companies reasonably well.  Thus, the *probability* of bankruptcy (which is what LR is after) may be fairly similar at each level.  It would be easier to tell if you plotted the proportion of companies that undergo bankruptcy at each level of `cash on hand`, rather than two plots of raw numbers.

There are two other factors that you should consider here:  First, a chi-squared test assumes that the levels of your variables are unordered categories, but `cash on hand` clearly has an intrinsic order.  Agresti has argued that when using an ordinal variable as a predictor, you will do best to make educated guesses about the levels of each category and then use the corresponding numerical values as a single quantitative predictor variable instead of $k-1$ categorical predictors (i.e., dummies).  If your guess isn't perfect (and it really can't be) there will be some measurement error associated with this, but on the other hand, you will gain efficiency by utilizing more of the information available.  In the end, unless your guesses are wildly wrong, the latter effect is likely to outweigh the former.  In you case, I would use the middle of each level of `cash on hand` for a quantitative `coh` variable.  Picking a value for the last category `>12` is tricky, but a reasonable value is unlikely to cause large problems.

Second, there may be a curvilinear relationship between `cash on hand` and the probability of bankruptcy.  So you may want to try adding a squared term.

---

*Edit in response to comment:*
Your chi-squared test assumes that `cash on hand` is a categorical variable with 12 unordered levels (`0-1`, `1-2`, `2-3`, `3-4`, `4-5`, `5-6`, `6-7`, `7-8`, `8-9`, `9-10`, `10-11`, `11-12`, `>12`).  But certainly this is an ordinal relationship between these categories.  So instead, use a single quantitative predictor variable with the values `0.5, 1.5, ..., 11.5, 12.5`.  This will not be completely accurate, and measurement error in an $X$ variable will cost you power, but it is likely to be reasonably accurate, and will save you 10 degrees of freedom, which will increase power.  You are very likely to end up with a more powerful analysis, and will certainly have a more interpretable model.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I follow your comment about ordering of categorical variables. Can you please illustrate on "about the levels of each category and then use the corresponding numerical values as a single quantitative predictor variable instead of k−1 categorical predictors (i.e., dummies)."?