# How can I calculate the power of my analysis with binary response data?

Tags: binary-data, statistical-power, treatment-effect

I have three groups with ~ 15 individuals per group.

- Group 1 gets a treatment
- Group 2 is a control in the same area
- Group 3 is a further control in a different area

The response is binary, 1 or 0.

I want to determine the power of my study. I used [this calculator](https://clincalc.com/stats/samplesize.aspx) but would like a second opinion. Using the terms from that site:

I have:

- 2 independent study groups
- A dichotomous endpoint
- alpha = 0.05
- power = 80%
- 50% expected incidence in group 1
- 10% expected incidence in group 2
- an enrollment ratio of 2:1 because I lump my controls together (groups 2 and 3)

This gives a sample size of 14 for group 1 and 28 for group 2.

Comment: You are using logistic regression? Probable duplicates:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162294/multiple-logistic-regression-power-analysis,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26016/sample-size-for-logistic-regression

Comment: Why do you lump your controls together in the sample size calculations? That should make for an easier problem, so I guess it will underestimate the needed sample size!  You also need to specify how do you plan to do the test.

Comment: I group them because neither control gets affected by the treatment. I was thinking of using an Exact test or similar because I am limited by my sample size.

Comment: Well, but if the base rate depends on area then that should be accounted for in the analysis

Comment: There are many posts here about power analysis with exact tests:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+exact+test+answers%3A1

Comment: Base rates shouldn't depend on area in my case so I should be ok there. Thanks for the exact test link.

Comment: Also of interest:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259635/what-is-the-difference-using-a-fishers-exact-test-vs-a-logistic-regression-for,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205904/t-test-chi-squared-or-logistic-regression,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94016/choosing-between-chi-squared-logistic-regression-vs-difference-of-mean-tests-f,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125985/why-do-p-values-for-test-of-likelihood-ratio-vs-fishers-exact-test-not-agree